# Calling a sub, with passed variables, from within a function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that is called and requires 2 passed variables

here is the first line:
`Function dimErr(rngStart As Long, rngEnd As Long)`

Now in the middle of this function I call a sub:
`Call highlightLegitRows`

Then the function carries on as intended.

Now, my problem is I now have optional variables associated with this sub:

```
Sub highlightLegitRows(Optional ByVal rngStart As Long = 0, Optional ByVal rngEnd As Long = 0)
```

When calling this sub, with the same values that have already been passed through, like so:
`Call highlightLegitRows(rngStart, rngEnd)`
My function appears to simply end at this line.

For example, this:

```
Call highlightLegitRows(rngStart, rngEnd)
MsgBox "hello"
```

would NOT trigger the message box. However this would:

```
Call highlightLegitRows
MsgBox "hello"
```

The only difference is the addition of these optional passed variables in the sub. Any idea where I am going wrong?

I haven't posted the whole function and sub as they are lengthy and complex, but both were working as intended before the above change.

Comment: Is your "function" just a normal function, or are you using it as a UDF (i.e. calling it as part of a formula in Excel)?

Comment: It's not being called as part of a formula, the result of the function is boolean and used as part of another sub.

Comment: Hmmm - UDFs appear to just stop when they hit an error, which is why I suspected that as the cause.  Does your code have any `On Error GoTo` statements?  That could also cause your code to jump out of the subroutine with execution passed to the error-handler.

Comment: We can suggest a lot of things, but without seeing the code, we are blind hitting.

Comment: I guess the other thing to ask is ... does it still not reach the `MsgSub` when `rngStart` and `rngEnd` are both explicitly `0`?  i.e. is the problem caused by the **existence** of the parameters, or because of the **values** in the parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Your code under normal circumstances will work. For example

```
Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print dimErr(1, 2)
End Sub

Function dimErr(rngStart As Long, rngEnd As Long)
    Call highlightLegitRows(rngStart, rngEnd)
    MsgBox "hello"
End Function

Sub highlightLegitRows(Optional ByVal rngStart As Long = 0, _
                       Optional ByVal rngEnd As Long = 0)
    Rows(rngStart & ":" & rngEnd).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End Sub
```

But will not in the below scenario.

```
Sub Sample()
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Debug.Print dimErr(0, 0)        
Whoa:
End Sub

Function dimErr(rngStart As Long, rngEnd As Long)
    Call highlightLegitRows(rngStart, rngEnd)
    MsgBox "hello"
End Function

Sub highlightLegitRows(Optional ByVal rngStart As Long = 0, _
                       Optional ByVal rngEnd As Long = 0)
    Rows(rngStart & ":" & rngEnd).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End Sub
```

or even this

```
Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print dimErr(0, 0)
End Sub

Function dimErr(rngStart As Long, rngEnd As Long)
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    Call highlightLegitRows(rngStart, rngEnd)
    MsgBox "hello"
Whoa:
End Function

Sub highlightLegitRows(Optional ByVal rngStart As Long = 0, _
                       Optional ByVal rngEnd As Long = 0)
    Rows(rngStart & ":" & rngEnd).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End Sub
```

Please check your code for error handling. Is there something that is stopping (exiting the sub/function) on error?